# How can I configure jquery-ui datepicker to enable for selection only the last friday of each month?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

obviously I dont know much about JS so I try best to run the datepicker. In our picker, we wanted only be able to pick every last Friday of the month. I've already written the code for this and it should fit:

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [( (day==5 && date.getDate() > 23)), ''];
```

Now I would have to integrate this into my existing function. It doesn't work the way I've tried. Where is the mistake?

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    closeText:"Schließen",
    prevText:"Vorheriger",
    nextText:"Nächster;",
    currentText:"Heute",
    monthNames: ["Januar","Februar","März","April","Mai","Juni","Juli","August","September","Oktober","November","Dezember"],
    monthNamesShort:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Mai","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Okt","Nov","Dez"],
        dayNames:["Sonntag","Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag","Freitag","Samstag"],
        dayNamesShort:["So","Mo","Di","Mi","Do","Fr","Sa"],
    dayNamesMin:["So","Mo","Di","Mi","Do","Fr","Sa"],
    weekHeader:"Sm",
    firstDay:1
});
```

Hope you understand my problem and be able help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could easily generate a dropdown list of last Fridays.  That would be far easier for users and the code would be greatly simplified.  Is there a reason for using a date picker with such a narrowly limited set of dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the corresponding callback using the `beforeShowDay` key to the object passed to the `datepicker` function:

( **Note:** I have **also updated the algorithm** because under some circumstances (July 2020, Dec 2021) it would pick the two last Fridays and under some other (Feb 2019) it would not pick any Friday )

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    ...
    beforeShowDay: (date)=>{
       var monthDays = new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth() + 1,0).getDate();
       var day = date.getDay();
       return [( (day==5 && date.getDate() > monthDays - 7 )), ''];
    }
}
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ce2jtsxo/2/)

[Working example (your algorithm)](https://jsfiddle.net/ce2jtsxo/)

Comment: @Chris Keep in mind that your algorithm has some flaw. E.g. In `July 2020`, `December 2021` it picks the last two fridays.

Comment: @Chris Note: I have updated the answer to add a fix to the algorithm.